# Getting one column value specific order using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

This is kinda like a groupwise maximum question but bit different.

For a table like below, I need to get one row per ID but row contents need to be in specified `lang`, and if it not exists, it should return the row in another specified `lang` (the fallback).

For context, it can be imagined as a posts table for a blog, we need to display posts in German, but if some post does not exist in that language, we'll show the English version instead. The `de` (preferred) and `en` (fallback) language is known before the query and will be given as a parameter.

| ID | lang | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | en | English Title |
| 1 | de | German Title |
| 2 | en | Title, but only in English |
| 3 | de | Title, but only in German |

I'm trying to get this output; for preferred `lang` = `de` & fallback = `en`:

| ID | lang | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | de | German Title |
| 2 | en | Title, but only in English |
| 3 | de | Title, but only in German |

1: both languages exist, preferred one returned;
2: preferred does not exists so fallback language returned;
3: only preferred one exists and returned

I can come up with a solution using UNION (two queries with first one has lang=preferred, second is lang=fallback) but I feel there is a more appropriate solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to get the IDs for which there is no `lang = 'de'`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.lang = 'de'
   OR (
        t1.lang = 'en'
        AND
        NOT EXISTS (
                     SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2
                     WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.lang = 'de'
                   )
      )
```

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you could use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT ID, lang, name
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY ID 
      ORDER BY lang = 'de' DESC, lang = 'en' DESC
    ) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided `window functions` are supported (v8) a simple solution uses `row_number` to assign a rank to each language

```
select Id, Lang, Name from (
    select *, 
    Row_Number() over(partition by id order by case when lang='de' then 1 else 2 end) rn
    from t
)t
where rn=1
```

See [example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7248ee4dcc7dec1a3aec6f34186c29a0)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple languages and want to filter out anything that is not DE or EN:

```
select Id, Lang, Name
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by case lang when 'de' then 1 when 'en' then 2 end) as seqnum
      from t
      where lang in ('de', 'en')
     )t
where seqnum = 1;
```

There are other fun approaches to this.  One I like uses `group by`:

```
select id, 
       coalesce(max(case when lang = 'de' then name end),
                max(case when lang = 'en' then name end)
               )
from t
where lang in ('de', 'en')
group by id;
```

Comment: I really liked the last approach. In my real application there is a need to ORDER BY name, so unfortunately I cannot use it here, but I'll keep in mind. Thank you.